# Finding centre of rotation for a set of points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, rotation, transformation

If I have an arbitrary set of points, and then the same set of points rotated by some degree, does anyone know of any algorithms to calculate/estimate where the centre of the rotation is? Or an area of study where these kinds of algorithms are needed?
I am having trouble finding any relevant information.

Thanks

Comment: The Earth _rotates_ on its axis. It _revolves_ around the Sun. To which are you referring?

Comment: Is the correspondence between the points known ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.


Answer (score 9):

Lets say you have one point (x, y), that moved to (x', y').

Then the center of rotation must lie on the line that is perpendicular to (x,y)-(x',y'), and that intersects the center (x,y)-(x',y').

Now take another point, (x2, y2), that moved to (x'2, y'2). This also gives rise to a line on which the center of rotation must be located on.

Now take these two lines and compute the intersection. There you have the center of rotation.

---

Update: If you don't have the correspondence of which point went where, it shouldn't be too hard to figure out. Here is a suggestion from top of my head: Find the center of mass of the "before"-points. Order the points according to their distance from this point. Now do the same with the "after"-points. The order of the two sets should now match. (The point closest to the center of mass *before* rotation, should be the point closest to the center of mass *after* rotation.)

Comment: this algorithm is good when he knows the relationship between points. in two different items.

Comment: That's a good process if you understand the correlation between the points, i.e. if they're labeled, but if they're arbitrary beforehand and after, the question becomes much more difficult (due to the identity problem; how do you identify that a point is the same before and after rotation?).

Comment: Who says he hasn't? And even if he doesn't have this relationship, he needs to figure it out before solving the entire problem, and from the point he *has* figured it out, this algorithm will help him.

Comment: Nobody says he hasn't; you've answered the problem well for a given subset of a problem.  OP hasn't specified precisely that that's the subset yet

Comment: If your short lines are parallel the eq system may be degenerate ..

Comment: Sorry for not specifying the full problem, this is a fantastic starting point, thanks (Y)

Comment: @philbert .. Do you know the correspondence between your initial and final points? Do you know which one in the initial state corresponds to every final point?

Comment: @McWafflestix, comments on the update are welcome :)

Comment: @belisarius, On the other hand, there are many degenerate cases where it is impossible to figure out the rotation. Four points in a square, before, and after or all points on equal distance lying on a circle for instance...

Comment: @aioobe Exactly what I was starting to think, which brings up the interesting question of what is or isn't a degenerate case then?

Comment: @SaeedAlg, If you believe I got the update from your answer, you're wrong. I simply suggest to use the center of mass to figure out the relationship between the before-points and after-points. As I understand it your answer is completely different.

Comment: @aioobe, I suggest use center of mass and convex hull, you suggest center of mass and nearest point, you updated your answer after you left a comment for me.

Comment: @aioobe: okay, here goes.  For an arbitrary set of points, the degenerate cases become a problem; in particular, the more points you add, the more likely you are to get a situation where your algorithms are unable to handle the cases.

Comment: @aioobe Exactly. If the geometry of the system has some rotational symmetry, the solution is not unique

Comment: Just an idea, but if you don't know the correspondence between the points, may it is possible to do a linear regression of the points before and after the rotation.

Comment: @belisarius, ah, "rotational symmetry". Thats a nice way to put it.

Comment: @aioobe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry

Answer (score 3):

It would be crazy overkill for this type of problem, but I think the functionality of the [generalized Hough transform](http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS791E/Notes/GeneralizedHough.pdf) for object detection at least encompasses what you want, even though it's not quite meant for this purpose.

Given an arbitrary shape created from a set of points, and another arbitrary set of points, it tries to find the shape in the set of the points even though it's been rotated, scaled, and translated. You might be able to take out the scaling and translation and get what you want.

Basically what it would come down to is brute forcing possible rotation points to see which one fit the second set of points best.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting problem.  My knowledge on this is a bit out of date, but as I recall, there's some research in the use of subgraph analysis on this; that is, characterizing subsections of the set of points by the distances between the points and the variances therein, and then correlating those subgraph analyses between the before and after rotations.

This is, of course, assuming a very complex set of points with a nonuniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some signature on your data set that allows to identify the points from the first set (A) with those on the second set (B).

An easy way is as follows:

- For every element E in A, find the two nearest points (N1, N2) and calculate the angle between N1,E,N2 resulting in three values: the angle and the distances from E to N1 and N2 (ang, d1, d2).
- Find 3 points in A with unique tuples (ang, d1, d2).
- For every element in B calculate also the distance to its two nearest neighbors and the angle. Find the 3 points matching those selected from A.
- Calculating the rotation is just a matter of geometric analysis.

**update**: you need 3 points to determine the rotation in 3D space. In 2D, two will do.

**update 2**: as others have commented on other posts, there may be symmetries in A that would stop you for finding the 3 unique triplets for (ang, d1, d2). In that case, for every one of the selected three points in A, you will have to perform a search over all the elements in B matching their triplets until some combination results in a rotation that works for all the elements in A.